# Local Boolean not registered

Tags: android, boolean

I am currently attempting to add in a simple alert dialog on a 'Stop' preference. Kind of like a stop button.

I am having trouble with managing local and public Booleans. I am using SharedPreferences to send the setting StopSetting across activities without actually opening the other activity.

However, the problem comes when I try to edit the boolean 'StopTrue'. When I set a default, blank boolean StopTrue in anywhere of the code, and then attempt to edit the boolean with the Shared Preferences editor, the two variables are registered as seperate variables. And so, the blank variable is registered as unused, and the edited variable is set to be 'always true' or 'always false.'

Does anyone know what the problem is here?
The code is below:

```
final Button StopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StopButton);
        StopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Creates Dialog
                AlertDialog.Builder StopDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                StopDialog.setTitle(R.string.Stop_Title);
                StopDialog.setMessage(R.string.Stop_Message);
                StopDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.Yes_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        boolean StopTrue = true;
                        SharedPreferences StopSetting = getSharedPreferences("StopSetting", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor StopEditor = StopSetting.edit();
                        StopEditor.putBoolean("StopSetting", StopTrue);
                        StopEditor.apply();
                        //Closes box
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                StopDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.No_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        boolean StopTrue = false;
                        SharedPreferences StopSetting = getSharedPreferences("StopSetting", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor StopEditor = StopSetting.edit();
                        StopEditor.putBoolean("StopSetting", StopTrue);
                        StopEditor.apply();
                        //Closes box
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                StopDialog.setNeutralButton(R.string.Negative_Button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Closes box
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare StopTrue as a global variable and only assign that variable in `onClick` methods

```
//declare this as global variable
Use boolean StopTrue; 
 @Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
  StopTrue = true;
  .....

}
```

and

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
   StopTrue = false;
   .......
}
```

Otherwise for each onClick instance , the StopTrue variable will be having the corresponding assigned values.